# How do I create multiple forms?

Tags: 8, forms

I want to create two modules for two forms. How can I achieve that? 
Namespace of both file will get conflict or not?

I am trying for this, and getting one error don't know its because of the two form or not.

**Folder structure1:**

```
modules->custom->amazing_forms
                   ->amazing_forms.info.yml
                   ->amazing_forms.routing.yml
                   ->src  
                       ->Formss
                          ->ContributeForm.php
```

**Folder Structure2**

```
modules->resume
           ->resume.info.yml
           ->resume.routing.yml
           ->src  
              ->Form
                 ->ResumeForm.php
```

**Error:**

```
InvalidArgumentException: Class "\Drupal\amazing_forms\Formss\ContriForm" does not exist. in Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ClassResolver->getInstanceFromDefinition() (line 29 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal8\core\lib\Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ClassResolver.php).
```

I have a question: Controller name should be `Form` only or we can use any other name for other modules as I have used above?

Comment: This is hard to answer because at a glance all your errors are a result of typos. Beyond that, there is no code listed, and I bet there are typos in your namespace declarations, too. Every form lives under `src/Form`. `ContriForm does not exist` is a legitimate error because it doesn't exist, it should be `ContributeForm`.